# Querying a UDP gameserver

Tags: php, python

I've been looking at [GameQ (PHP)](https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ/tree/v3/src/GameQ) and trying to convert the [Ase](https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ/blob/v3/src/GameQ/Protocols/Ase.php) protocol to Python.

I've tried using this code but it keeps going indefinitely and does not return anything.

```
import socket

HOST = "" #external host
PORT = 22126


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(b's', (HOST, PORT))
print(sock.recv(1024))
```

Comment: What you mean by _going indefinitely_ , and what you expect to return , it sends a character `s` to a server

Comment: It's meant to return info about the gameserver, looking at the ASE protocol (link in OP) it sends `s` which is why I've tried to send it hoping for the response I'm looking for.

Comment: You are reading the receive buffer immediately after sending. Usually the answer is going to take some time.

Comment: Wouldn't it still end eventually though? Since I posted this it still hasn't exited. I just had to force exit.

Comment: @Nathan check that the server is responding (using tcpdump or wireshark for example) or try running 'netcat $HOST $PORT' to see if the server behaves.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. Netcat doesn't seem to work with it (even with the `-u` flag) but it still does in PHP.